# Get specific JFrame component to change its value

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame called MainFrame where almost all of the components for my application are found. It has a JTabbedPane and lots of JPanels to group components. Now I have to build some custom cell editors or buttons that affect a lot of components on my JFrame and some helper classes, that need information from many components in my JFrame. What I've done so far is to pass these components/values of components to the constructor of helper classes or to custom editors which sometimes a lot of components. I feel like there is something wrong with it. Like I'm passing a lot of values from the constructor. I'm thinking of just passing the MainFrame and get its components. How can I get these components from the MainFrame and the specific components that I need? Or suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all your frame components by:

```
Component[] components1=mFrame.getContentPane().getComponents();
```

You can get sub-components of the main containers by:

```
// Assuming component is a container
((Container)component).getComponents();
```

You can get component name by:

```
Component.getName();
```

Comment: I think the `component` in the last snippet should be in lower case?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a HashMap gui and put any component you want to that map. Then get the components u need like gui.get("myButtonID"); Putting the component's name in Map may be good idea.

Comment: Putting every component into a Map can be a bit tedious and error prone, especially if you have a big set of UI code generated by something like NetBeans!